# How can I add convolutional layer to this problem?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network

I am a newbie in Convents, I designed a three-layer network, with 2 hidden layers to classify images.

I was wondering how can I add 2 layers to the network? 
I understand that early stopping might be a bit hard to tune. I just want to plot training loss and the validation error to do the comparison with the one that does not have convnet (The code that I already wrote posted here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you want to add conv layer?
Conv2D gets (N, H, W, C) as inputs and outputs,
where N is batch size, H is height, W is width and C is channel size.

Your network has all (N, C) tensor. So, You need Reshape vector into images, or Flatten images into vector.

Here is an example that get (NHWC) tensor, so you don't need x_train.reshape to flatten. Many famous network like VGG, ResNet has Conv layer first, and Dense layer at last. It aims to get feature from conv layers, and predict class by Dense layer.

```py
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Conv2D, Flatten
from keras import regularizers
import numpy as np


(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# MNIST shape has lacks of channels, so add it. MNIST is gray scale so channel size is 1.
# (60000, 28, 28) -> (60000, 28, 28, 1)
# If you have color image, it shoud be 3 channels, RGB: [BATCH_SIZE, H, W, 3]
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=-1)

num_classes = 10
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model_3 = Sequential()
model_3.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model_3.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model_3.add(Flatten())
model_3.add(Dense(256, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model_3.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_3.add(Dense(128, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model_3.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_3.add(Dense(64, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model_3.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_3.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model_3.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model_3.fit(
    x_train, y_train,
    batch_size=128,
    epochs=250,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

For Reshape, https://keras.io/layers/core/

And There is Conv2D MNIST sample.
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py

Comment: thank you. based on your comment, can you pls edit the code? I would understand your explanation better.